# How can i decode and get relevant data from envelope_xdr

Tags: javascript-sdk

I know that `Stellar.xdr.TransactionEnvelope.fromXDR` can decode data of a record called `envelope_xdr`. But what I do not understand is how I can get all data I need like `memo`, `sourceAccount` etc. Because those 2 for example are displayed on response as

```
function () {  this.get(name); }
```

Do I need to install another package of stellar? Currently I'm using only stellar-sdk for JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`const transaction = new StellarSdk.Transaction(txenv);`

This will decode an transaction envelope XDR object to a Transaction object (https://github.com/stellar/js-stellar-base/blob/master/src/transaction.js), which has all of the properties you need.

Comment: hmm this is the same as using :
Stellar.xdr.TransactionEnvelope.fromXDR(historyPage.records[1].envelope_xdr, 'base64')
problem is that i cannot get the property of memo or sourceAccount as i said on my question

Comment: Source account would be `transaction.source`, and memo `transaction.memo`. If not, maybe something is wrong with your XDR?

Comment: ok, source i can get .but memo gives me a buffer result. how do i decrypt it ? on stellar tool i gave the envelop and they could print my memo. i do not know how they decrypt the buffer

Comment: Depends on the memo type. For a hash you'd probably want to convert the bytes to a string of hex characters (`buf.toString('hex');`);

Comment: its a text type this i why i do not know how to convert the buffer to a string.

Comment: `buf.toString();`usually does the trick